# Make second monitor show workspace that's on the left of primary monitor

Tags: unity, nvidia, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I have been searching for a while now, but didn't find the thing I want.

I have 3x4 raster of workspaces. I want to configure the workspaces as such that **the second monitor shows the workspace that is on the left of my primary monitor.**

I'd be happy if the second monitor only shows the workspace, but Ideally, I would be able to work on that workspace without switching it to my primary monitor. It should work like this:

```
l   r   -   -                                -   l   r   -
-   -   -   -   switch primary workspace     -   -   -   -
-   -   -   -   one-to-right-->              -   -   -   -
```

`- - - -` are positions of my workspaces and `l/r` are the workspaces displayed by the left (secundary) / right (primary) monitor:

Hopefully I made clear what I'd like to have and it is not too specific. Are there any hacks to make it happen?

For clarification:  What I do **not** want is:

1. Switch workspaces individually on my monitors
2. Pin an application to my left (or right) monitor

Comment: I've been struggling with similar issues, mostly around window management across multiple monitors, since switching to Ubuntu 6 months ago.  This is one of 3 big reasons I'll prob switch to win10.

Comment: It is annoying, but it's no reason to give up multiple desktops for good - A feature that should have been in Windows since at least Win Vista or 7. And that's one of the less important reasons why Windows is evil, but I don't wanna start a debate of principles here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extremely clear what you're asking and a really neat idea but unfortunately this is impossible without digging deep into the bowels of the Window Manager and changing the code there.

Workspaces are duplications of your physical monitor set-up and what you're trying to do would create a bunch of problems if your monitors do not have the exact same resolution: windows would have to be moved to fit on the screen when changing around, or panning would need to be enabled automatically, etc, ...

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: I already feared for something like this, however hope springs eternal....

Comment: The only thing I could do was upvote your answer...  I don't even think making it an Ubuntu feature request would help as it's programmatically just too complex to ever make it through the selection process.  Still a genius idea though!  **;-)**