# How to make a second monitor appear to the left

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

I have a laptop that i attach via HDMI a second screen to when i'm at home. The thing is that the monitor is physically to the left of my laptop, that is just the way the desk is arranged, and that is very difficult to change (the keyboard is with the notebook and it would be uncomfortable to swap notebook and the screen around).

I can, of course, chose to have the HDMI screen to the left of my notebook screen, but that causes it to be the first screen (with the menu moving there), that is not what i want. I want my first screen to remain my notebook screen, and the second screen to be to the left.

I am running XUbuntu

```
$ cat lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
```

Note: This is not a duplicate of [Make second monitor show workspace that's on the left of primary monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591489/make-second-monitor-show-workspace-thats-on-the-left-of-primary-monitor)

Comment: Did you tried using `arandr` to arrange and configure your monitors visually?

Comment: @bistoco, Ok, that. Together wish setting the panel to 'Primary' rather than 'Automatic' has resolved it. Thanks

Comment: @bistoco After looking at this solution a bit longer it is increadibly buggy. It worked at first, but if the screen is disconnected and reattached, XUbuntu gets confused. On the second monitor maximised applications assume that there is a panel that isn't there and do not reach to the top, but in the main screen the maximised window will actually overlap the panel.

Comment: Well, your setup was "buggy" before. `arandr` is just a front-end for xrandr , and it sets the screen configuration "at the current state", it won't save it and apply it for future connects/disconnects. The best scenario for you will be configure with `arandr`, save that config as a script, and either have a background process to look for changes and apply the config, or run it manually when you disconnect/connect again.

Comment: @bistoco How would i 'save it as a script'?

Comment: `Menu > Layout > Save As`